# How to colour new String?

Tags: android, eclipse, string

How ist it possible to colour the newText "e"?

```
public void onClick(View v) {

String text = tw.getText().toString();

int n = 4;      

String newText = text.substring(0, n) + "e" + text.substring(n + 1);

tw.setText(newText);
```

Comment: I suggest using an HTML `<font>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `ForegroundColorSpan`

```
    final String text = "something something text";
    final int n = 4;
    final String newText = text.substring(0, n) + "e" + text.substring(n + 1);

    final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
    final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(newText);
    ss.setSpan(fcs, n, n + 1, 0);

    tv.setText(ss);
```

Comment: Thx, but with this code the letter before the "e" gets red...?! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you formate the String with html

You need to use Html.fromHtml() to use HTML in your XML Strings. Simply referencing a String with HTML in your layout XML will not work.

For example:

```
  String text = "<font color=#cc0029>Exempl</font> <font color=#ffcc00>e</font>";
  myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text);
```